# How to write \models symbols backwards

Tags: equations

that's it. Can't seem to find it anywhere else online so I thought this might be the place where someone knows

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are several packages, such as `MnSymbol` or `fdsymbol`, that contain this symbol. The symbols provided by these packages might be rendered a bit smaller than the regular `\models` symbol, but both packages provide `\leftmodels` and `\rightmodels` which fit in size.

Answer (score 7):

The standard definition for `\models` is

```
\mathrel{|}\joinrel\Relbar
```

so you can do the same backwards:

```
\newcommand{\sledom}{\Relbar\joinrel\mathrel{|}}
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sledom}{\Relbar\joinrel\mathrel{|}}

\begin{document}

$M\models \varphi$

$\varphi\sledom M$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The Comprehensive list suggests a similar definition, but I prefer to use `\Relbar`, because we can redefine it to get rid of the small gap (and this won't interfere with other usages of `\Relbar`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\Relbar}{\mathrel{\mkern-0.5mu=\mkern-0.5mu}}
\newcommand{\sledom}{\Relbar\joinrel\mathrel{|}}
\MakeRobust{\Relbar}
\MakeRobust{\sledom}

\begin{document}

$M\models \varphi$

$\varphi\sledom M$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is (in a slightly different way) also suggested in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (on page 258).

Comment: @JasperHabicht On my machine it's on page 260, but it's not easy to find and the definition is slightly different: I'd prefer `\Relbar` that can be modified rather than hardwiring `=`.

Comment: It is in fact on page 260! Sorry, my bad. I only stumbled upon it when I searched thie PDF for "models".

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is the `turnstile` package ([documentation here](https://ctan.org/pkg/turnstile?lang=en)), which provides additional options for placing symbols above and below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma \sdtstile{}{} P \qquad \Gamma \sdtstile{\mathrm{L}}{x,y} P$

$\Gamma \ndststile{}{} P \qquad \Gamma \ndststile{\mathrm{LC}}{x,y,z,w} P$

\end{document}
```